# Name for concept: each pair of sets is either nested or disjoint

Tags: terminology, sets

Does this property have a name?

> Given a collection of sets $\mathcal{P}$, for   all pairs $A, B\in\mathcal{P}$, either $A\cap B=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

This concept could equally apply to monoids, groups, partial orders or other mathematical structures, with some adjustments to the definitions. For instance, for monoids and groups we would replace $A\cap B=\emptyset$ by $A\cap B=\{\epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon$ is the unit of the monoid/group.

Comment: Embarassing: I asked the [same question before](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26694/terminology-for-relation-on-sets/26696#26696).

Comment: In the light of [our recent discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/704/what-kinds-of-mathematics-do-we-consider-computer-science-enough-to-be-ontopic-h), I think I have to ask: what is the relation to CS here, that is which concept are you trying to model?

Comment: @Raphael: The concept came up while investigating models of software product lines. I distilled the essence, and chose more basic mathematical structures as the basis of the question. Had I included all the details about software product lines in order to phrase the question, ... well, it wouldn't have been so easy to get a clear answer so quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that's called a *laminar family*.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/26696/10833

Comment: @DaveClarke I think we should thank adrianN. I have been looking for the name of that property myself for a while. I missed your previous question and I never bother to ask. This property is hard to search. Thanks to adrianN again.

Comment: Everybody seems to be happy, but can you please give a reference so the answer holds more weight for future visitors? (The link to MO does not quite count.)